# Published Maui app with errors that don't happpen in Debug

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, syncfusion

I've been learning .NET by developing an app and today I decided to publish it and test it.

When I run my code in debug mode, in Microsoft Visual Studio, there are no errors and everything goes smoothy.

In the published app, I get a massive error when trying to go to the Main Page, after login in, that doesn't happen when I'm debugging.

The crash happens after the user presses the login button. My code checks that everything is correct and the `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(MainPage)}");` is called.

The following is the error I get after that.

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
StackTrace :    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.SetPropertyValue(Object xamlelement, XmlName propertyName, Object value, Object rootElement, INode node, HydrationContext context, IXmlLineInfo lineInfo)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.Visit(ValueNode node, INode parentNode)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ValueNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.RootNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Visit(RootNode rootnode, HydrationContext visitorContext, Boolean useDesignProperties)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load(Object view, String xaml, Assembly rootAssembly, Boolean useDesignProperties)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load(Object view, String xaml, Boolean useDesignProperties)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load(Object view, Type callingType)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml[TXaml](TXaml view, Type callingType)
   at VersionControl.Views.MainPage.InitializeComponent()
   at VersionControl.Views.MainPage..ctor(MainPageViewModel viewModel)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Maui.MauiContext.WrappedServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellContent.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.IShellContentController.GetOrCreateContent>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ElementTemplate.CreateContent()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals.DataTemplateExtensions.CreateContent(DataTemplate self, Object item, BindableObject container)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellContent.Microsoft.Maui.Controls.IShellContentController.GetOrCreateContent()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.ShellSectionHandler.SyncNavigationStack(Boolean animated, NavigationRequestedEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.ShellSectionHandler.MapCurrentItem(ShellSectionHandler handler, ShellSection item)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper`2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Add>b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String key, IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.ShellSectionHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.ShellItemHandler.UpdateCurrentItem()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.ShellItemHandler.MapCurrentItem(ShellItemHandler handler, ShellItem item)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper`2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Add>b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String key, IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.ShellItemHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.ShellView.CreateShellItemView()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.ShellView.SwitchShellItem(ShellItem newItem, Boolean animate)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.ShellHandler.MapCurrentItem(ShellHandler handler, Shell view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper`2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Add>b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String key, IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperty(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView, String property)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.UpdateValue(String property)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Shell.OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValueActual(BindableProperty property, BindablePropertyContext context, Object value, Boolean currentlyApplying, SetValueFlags attributes, Boolean silent)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValueCore(BindableProperty property, Object value, SetValueFlags attributes, SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellNavigationManager.GoToAsync(ShellNavigationParameters shellNavigationParameters, ShellNavigationRequest navigationRequest)
   at VersionControl.ViewModels.LoadingViewModel.PressMe()
System.NullReferenceException
Message : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
StackTrace :    at Syncfusion.Maui.ListView.SfListView.SetUpKeyListenerRequirements()
   at Syncfusion.Maui.ListView.SfListView.RaiseListViewLoaded(ListViewLoadedEventArgs e)
   at Syncfusion.Maui.ListView.SfListView.ArrangeContent(Rect bounds)
   at Syncfusion.Maui.Core.SfView.set_Padding(Thickness value)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
```

After a few tries I noticed that if I remove my Syncfusion List and Grid the page loads, so the problem must be there.

But still, I dont understand why it works in debug mode and not in the published app.

Below, a part of my xaml code, from the Main page. If I run this bit it breaks because of the SfList.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:VersionControl.ViewModels"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="VersionControl.Views.MainPage"
             xmlns:syncfusionList="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Maui.ListView;assembly=Syncfusion.Maui.ListView"
             xmlns:syncfusionGrid="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Maui.DataGrid;assembly=Syncfusion.Maui.DataGrid"
             xmlns:core="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Maui.Core;assembly=Syncfusion.Maui.Core"
             BackgroundColor="#212121">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- First Column -->
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <Image Source="folder_icon.png" HeightRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="20,45,0,0"></Image>
            <Button Text="{Binding FolderName}" Command="{Binding FolderCommand}" 
                    ToolTipProperties.Text="Click to open Windows Explorer to the default location for your projects."
                    BackgroundColor="#212121" BorderColor="#212121" Padding="0" TextColor="LightGrey" FontSize="Subtitle" Margin="50,40,0,0" 
                    MinimumHeightRequest="1" WidthRequest="120" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" CornerRadius="4">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroupList>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="DimGrey" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateGroupList>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Button>
            <Button Text="+New" Command="{Binding AddSubFolderCommand}" BackgroundColor="#212121" BorderColor="#212121" Padding="0" 
                   TextColor="LightGrey" FontSize="Body" Margin="245,45,0,0" MinimumHeightRequest="1" WidthRequest="50" CornerRadius="4"
                   HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start"
                   ToolTipProperties.Text="Create a new project and folder at the same time.">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroupList>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="DimGrey" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateGroupList>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Button>
            <syncfusionList:SfListView x:Name="listView" Padding="10" AutoFitMode="Height" ItemSpacing="10,5,0,0" Margin="10,100,0,0"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProject}" 
                                    SelectionBackground="DimGray" SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectedProjectSyncCommand}">
                <syncfusionList:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Image Source="folder2.png" HeightRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsVisible="{Binding OnlyLocalProjectFolder}"></Image>
                            <Image Source="cloud2.png" HeightRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsVisible="{Binding OnlyS3ProjectFolder}" Margin="0,0,0,0"></Image>
                            <Image Source="foldercloud.png" HeightRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsVisible="{Binding LocalAndS3ProjectFolder}"></Image>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="13" TextColor="LightGrey" Margin="30,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                            <Image Source="correct.png" IsVisible="false" HeightRequest="12" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,0,20,0">
                                <Image.Triggers>
                                    <MultiTrigger TargetType="Image">
                                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding UpToDateLocal}" Value="true" />
                                            <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding UpToDateS3}" Value="true" />
                                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="true" />
                                    </MultiTrigger>
                                </Image.Triggers>
                            </Image>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroupList>
                                    <VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="DimGray"/>
                                            </VisualState.Setters>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateGroupList>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </syncfusionList:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
            </syncfusionList:SfListView>
        </Grid>
```

Could you help understand what is wrong?

EDIT:

If I run from vs, in release mode, I get the following error:

```
System.NullReferenceException
Message : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
StackTrace :    at Syncfusion.Maui.ListView.SfListView.SetUpKeyListenerRequirements()
   at Syncfusion.Maui.ListView.SfListView.RaiseListViewLoaded(ListViewLoadedEventArgs e)
   at Syncfusion.Maui.ListView.SfListView.ArrangeContent(Rect bounds)
   at Syncfusion.Maui.Core.SfView.set_Padding(Thickness value)
   at VersionControl.Views.MainPage.InitializeComponent()
   at VersionControl.Views.MainPage..ctor(MainPageViewModel viewModel)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Maui.MauiContext.WrappedServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellContent.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.IShellContentController.GetOrCreateContent>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ElementTemplate.CreateContent()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellContent.Microsoft.Maui.Controls.IShellContentController.GetOrCreateContent()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.ShellSectionHandler.SyncNavigationStack(Boolean animated, NavigationRequestedEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.ShellSectionHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.ShellItemHandler.UpdateCurrentItem()
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.ShellItemHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.ShellView.CreateShellItemView()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.ShellView.SwitchShellItem(ShellItem newItem, Boolean animate)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Shell.OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValueActual(BindableProperty property, BindablePropertyContext context, Object value, Boolean currentlyApplying, SetValueFlags attributes, Boolean silent)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValueCore(BindableProperty property, Object value, SetValueFlags attributes, SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellNavigationManager.GoToAsync(ShellNavigationParameters shellNavigationParameters, ShellNavigationRequest navigationRequest)
   at VersionControl.ViewModels.LoadingViewModel.PressMe()
```

Comment: what is the inner exception?

Comment: Make a release build, without publishing. Run that from VS. Same error?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve just edited my post with the error

Comment: @Jason, I never did an inner exception, will check what it means and post it

Comment: I just found out that Padding in the ListView was causing the error

Comment: I still don't understand why that same Padding in debug raises no error and in release yes

Comment: Normally the point is that that in release you might have code executed in a different order that on debug, mainly because it's faster. So for example, you might have the case of Debug: some internal values are set, then accessed. Release: code that access unfilled valued maybe executed crashing on nulls, because variables were not set yet. If that comes from the custom control you can do nothing, it's their fault.

Comment: Coming from a custom control the only hack i can see to avoid this is to create the problematic control manually after the page in created..